# How can I find the LDAP server in the DNS on Windows?

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, ldap, nslookup

For Linux, this command should return the DNS record for the LDAP server

```
host -t srv _ldap._tcp.DOMAINNAME
```

(found at [Authenticating from Java (Linux) to Active Directory using LDAP WITHOUT servername](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091984))

How could I get the same on the Windows command line using nslookup?

I tried

```
nslookup -type srv _ldap._tcp.DOMAINNAME
```

(following http://support.microsoft.com/kb/200525), would this be correct?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You need to use an `=` after `-type`:

```
nslookup -type=srv _ldap._tcp.DOMAINNAME
```

Comment: still can't get

Answer (score 16):

In cmd shell:

```
nslookup 
set types=all
_ldap._tcp
```

Comment: Or, in one line `nslookup -type=all _ldap._tcp`.  Wanted so I could redirect output to a file.

Answer (score 9):

None of the above worked for me, I got every time an error like this (I've tried with all the combinations I can think of with the domain names):

*** Unknown can't find _ldap._tcp: Non-existent domain

So another google search pointed to this method:

```
nltest /dclist:yourdomain.com
```

And this results in the list of the different servers in my network. Hope this saves an additional 2 minutes for someone else.

Comment: nltest returned the correct information when using the "short" domain name, this short name did not resolve on the nslookup query

Answer (score 5):

[How to verify Service Location (SRV) locator resource records for a domain controller after you install the Active Directory directory service.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/816587)

Use Nslookup to verify the SRV records, follow these steps:

1. Click Start, and then click Run.
2. In the Open box, type **cmd**.
3. Type **nslookup**, and then press ENTER.
4. Type **set type=all**, and then press ENTER.
5. Type **_ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.Domain_Name**, where Domain_Name is the name of your domain, and then press ENTER.

Answer (score 2):

`Get-ADDomainController` will list your domain controllers from domain
If you want to check it from another domain then use `-server` switch.

```
get-addomaincontroller -server "domain"
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows cmd prompt uses "query" instead of "type" for some forsaken reason. Interactive nslookup still uses "set type=srv".

nslookup -query=srv _ldap._tcp.DOMAINNAME

EDIT: while "query" works it seems that I am 100% wrong. "type" works too.

Comment: Are you sure about that? `nslookup -type=srv _ldap._tcp.DOMAINNAME` works as expected on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

"nslookup -query=srv _ldap._tcp.DOMAINNAME" worked for me, tried nslookup -type=srv _ldap._tcp.DOMAINNAME and didn't work.

Server 2008 R2